# Scanner String Confusion

Tags: java, input

The Programm is supposed to let me enter a value a and a string. While it lets me input he integer when it comes to the string, it prints the question but does not let me enter anything.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrSumN {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Enter a value");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    int pr = 1;
    System.out.println("Do you want the sum of the numbers or the products of the numbers?");
    String answer = sc.nextLine();
    //Itdoesnotletmeinputmystringatthispoint
    if (answer == "sum") {
      sum(a, sum);
    } else {
      product(a, pr);
    }
  }

  public static void sum(int a, int sum) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      sum = sum + (a - i);
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is " + sum);
  }

  public static void product(int a, int pr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      pr = pr * (a - i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please take some time to format your code so that it is easier for the community to read and help you.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336626/in-java-should-i-use-a-different-scanner-instance-for-different-types-of-input?rq=1

Comment: Re `if (answer=="sum") {`: you should also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you call `int a = sc.nextInt();` you enter an integer in the console and press enter. The integer you entered gets stored in `a`, whereas the **newline character (`\n`) is read by your `String answer = sc.nextLine();`** and so it doesn't accept a string from you.

Add this line

```
sc.nextLine(); // Will read the '\n' character from System.in
```

after

```
int a = sc.nextInt();
```

**Another method**: You can scan for a `string` instead of an `int` and get `a` by *parsing for `int`*:

```
try {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
}
catch (ParseException ex) { // Catch
}
```

**On another (side) note**, do not use `if (answer=="sum")`, instead you would want to use

```
if (Object.equals (answer, "sum")
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: Note that you don't really need to use `Object.equals`, since neither argument is null - you can just use `answer.equals("sum")` (or `"sum".equals(answer)`).

Comment: That is true - Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After this line:

```
int a = sc.nextInt();
```

Add this:

```
sc.nextLine();
```

The reason you need to add `sc.nextLine()` is because `nextInt()` does not consume the newline.

Alternatively, you may scan for a String and parse it to the respective type, for example:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

---

**Add**: And something not related to your primary question, when comparing the value of a String, use `.equals` and not `==`.

We use `==` to compare identity, so it should be:

```
if (answer.equals("sum"))
```